# Vuetify Add keyup.enter to v-if route path

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js, keyup

I would like to add a keyup.enter link here. this is possible with one click: to = "link.route". however keyup.enter = "link.route" does not work.

```js
methods: {
            Test() {
                this.redirect(this.link.route, {key: this.link.text})
            }
        }
```

```html
            v-layout(justify-start align-start wrap)
                v-flex(shrink class="py-3" @keyup.enter="Test()")
                    template(v-for="link in navItemsFooter")

                        e-link-nav(v-if="link.route" class="white--text" @keyup.enter="Test()" tabindex="0" :key="link.text" :to="link.route" class="i-footer__item") {{ link.text }}
                        span(v-else) {{ link.text }}

                        span(v-if="link.separator" class="white--text i-footer__item-separator") |
```

Comment: Have you tried with `@keyup.enter="$router.push(link.route)"` ?

Comment: Unfortunately does not work

Comment: Your code snippet produces syntax error when the "Run code snippet" button is clicked.